# mdframed is causing wrong alignment at the bottom of pages

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, mdframed

If you would be so kind to compile this LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,twoside=true,lmargin=4cm,
rmargin=4cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{mdframed,lipsum,kantlipsum}
\mdfsetup{font=\small}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-8]


\begin{mdframed}
\kant[1-5]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

You will find that the bottoms of pages 2 and 3 are misaligned as follows:

[image: misaligned pages]

Questions:

1. Shouldn't the space between the paragraph and the frame on page 3 expand such that the bottoms align? Why does this not take place?
2. How would you add a flexible (zero, plus something flexible if needed, just like for paragraph spacing) space above the mdframed box too? That would put a less strain on the space between the paragraphs, assuming I resolve question 1 above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For reasons I don't understand, `mdframed` outputs the first (split) box in a way that the page bottom will be ragged no matter whether `\raggedbottom` or `\flushbottom` (default with `book`) is configured.

You can get a more normal behaviour with the following patches:

```
\usepackage{mdframed}

\makeatletter

\patchcmd\mdf@put@frame@i{\hrule \@height\z@ \@width\hsize\vfill}{}{}{}
\patchcmd\mdf@put@frame@i{\hrule \@height\z@ \@width\hsize\vfill}{}{}{}
\patchcmd\mdf@put@frame@i{\hrule \@height\z@ \@width\hsize\vfill}{}{}{}

\makeatother
```

As I really don't know what this is supposed to achieve, this will probably break something, but at least, the page bottom is aligned now ;-)

The space above the `mdframed` box is configured with `skipabove`, so you get flexible glue by

```
\mdfsetup{font=\small,skipabove=\parskip}
```

[image: example]

Comment: I didn't implement this because I like the alignment at the top ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Ah, Ok. That's a valid reason I suppose ;-) Is it documented behaviuor? btw, what exactly do you mean by top alignment? Usually one speaks about top/bottom alignment when things are arranged horizontally.

Comment: I mean the vertical alignment.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel What do you mean "alignment at the top"?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Of course "top" is a vertical alignment, but normally, vertical alignment only makes sense when things are displayed side by side (like parboxes or tables).

Comment: Inside vbox you can't work with glue expression and so `flushbotton` has no effect. After a splitting I have to decide the vertical alignment of the box regarding to the page dimension.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel That's not entirely true. When just saying `\eject` (as is effectively done with my patch), the output routine will decide about what happens, as for all other pages, or the user can decide by giving, for instance, `skipabove=0pt plus 1fill`.